# Relation between Legendre and Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Where I could find relationships between Legendre and Chebyshev polynomials?
For example I found with maple 
$$ P_n(\cos\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+k}\frac{2-\delta_{k0}}{4^n}
\binom{n-k}{\frac{n-k}{2}}\binom{n+k}{\frac{n+k}{2}}\cos(k\theta)$$
The sum runs over $n+k$ even, and $\delta_{k0}=1$ if and only if $k=0$. (And $\cos(k\theta)$ are the Chebyshev polynomials)

But would like to know how its proved, and what the inverse relationship is.
Are there any papers or books with these types of relationships?

Comment: Have you checked the Boyd's book on Chebyshev methods? http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/NEW/Math/MC_Calculus/MCat_Advanced%20calculus/Boyd%20J.P.%20Chebyshev%20and%20Fourier%20spectral%20methods%20(2ed.,%20Dover,%202000)(689s)_MCat_.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Legendre and Chebyshev polynomials are particular cases of Jacobi polynomials $P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$. A general connection formula of the type $$P_n^{(\gamma,\delta)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nc_{n,k}^{\gamma,\delta;\alpha,\beta}P_k^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$$ can be found on page 256 of the book [Mourad E.H. Ismail, *Classical and quantum orthogonal polynomials in one variable*,
Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications **98**, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2005].

Answer (score 3):

On pp.13~15 of *Fox, L. Parker. Chebyshev polynomials in numerical analysis. No. 519.4 F6. 1968.*, especially (64)(65), we can see the arguement. As an approach to the minimax solution to the function $\Pi(x)=(x-x_{0})\cdots(x-x_{n})$ with equal weights $w(x)=1$, we can write $$\Pi(x)=\frac{2^{n+1}(n+1)!^{2}}{(2n+2)!}P_{n+1}(x)$$ where $P_{k}(x)$ is a Legendre polynomial of degree $k$.

and by the orthogonal transformation provided there we could also write it in terms of weight $w(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^{2})}}$ and $$\Pi(x)=2^{-n}T_{n+1}(x)$$ where $T_{k}(x)$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of degree $k$.

And these two equalities gave identity involving both Legendre and Chebyshev polynomials.